# Using UIRefreshControl

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer, uirefreshcontrol

Currently, I have an application that is using `UIRefreshControl`.

I am having some issues though...

Heres my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.rearTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}


- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(endRefresh:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)endRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh
{
    [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

Pulling the tableview does initialize the `timer` but the `2` seconds are up... my app `crashes` and sends this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer endRefreshing]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c093c0'
```

I am confused :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Issue:

This issue occurs because:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(endRefresh:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

You are added the `endRefresh:` as the selector for the timer. So the parameter for the `endRefresh:` method will be a `NSTimer` not `UIRefreshControl`.

The actual method signature will look like:

```
- (void)endRefresh:(NSTimer *)refresh
{
   //your code
}
```

You are calling the `endRefreshing` `NSTimer` object, that's why the crash occurs.

Declaring like:

```
- (void)endRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh
```

Just typecast `NSTimer` object to `UIRefreshControl` nothing more.

It is equivalent to:

```
- (void)endRefresh:(NSTimer *)timer
{
   UIRefreshControl *refresh = (UIRefreshControl *)timer;
   [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

#### Solution 1:

Declare `UIRefreshControl` as a property and use it.

#### Solution 2:

Change your methods like:

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [self performSelector:@selector(endRefresh:) withObject:refreshControl afterDelay:2.0f];
}

- (void)endRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh
{
    [refresh performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```